# Does having a total gastrectomy (removal of the stomach) cause individuals to be more prone to infections?

Tags: infection, stomach, surgery

If a patient has a complete removal of his/her stomach (i.e. a [total gastrectomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrectomy)), then does that cause a person to be more prone to infections from eating unsanitary food?

I'm asking this question because the stomach plays a role in sterilizing food and, hence, without a stomach it would follow that one might be more prone to getting intestinal infections.

Comment: Yes.I think so as may of the bacteria are killed in our stomach

Comment: Yeah I think so too that's why I even asked the question -- to confirm what makes sense.

Comment: It would be nice to have empirical/epidemiological evidence to support this hypothesis.

Comment: I don't have time for a full right up, but here's a good starting [point.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23838912)